# GLES 3 primitive restart on iPad Pro

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, opengl-es

I am rendering dynamically loaded primitives (line strips, triangle strips) with OpenGL ES 3 on Apple hardware (>= iOS 8). The rendering is done via indexing. To save memory, I calculate the number of indices at runtime and choose between GLubyte, GLushort and GLuint as index buffer type.

For performance reasons, I want to render multiple distinct strips in a single drawcall which can be achieved using primitive restart (= inserting the largest index of the current type: 0xFF, 0xFFFF or 0xFFFFFFFF). To make this work, GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART_FIXED_INDEX must be enabled.

Everything works great on all iOS simulator versions and on most of the devices I tested (iPhone 6+, iPad mini 2). Problems arise on the iPad Pro (12,9"): If I choose GLubyte as buffer type, primitive restart does not work and 0xFF is interpreted as an actual index. GLushort and GLuint work as intended.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/catuld97ddrtdw3/U8IndexBuffers.zip?dl=0) you can find some sample code (Swift) with two triangles that are separated via primitive restart. Change the following line to switch between the buffer types:

```
//Which buffer to use?
private let indexbuffer = 0
```

0 is GLubyte, 1 is GLushort and 2 is GLuint. As I mentioned above, the error case is value of 0 on an iPad Pro.

Is it a graphics hardware bug on the iPad Pro? Can anybody confirm this or did I make some kind of error? Thanks in advance!